# QGIS Hide symbols which overlaping others

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry, overlapping-features

I have a layer with points located close to each other. Symbols which I have to set for each of point are overlapping. I would like to hide (or remove) those points which overlap (in other words I'd like to make a generalization). For example I have input layer:

[image]

And my expected result is something like this:

[image: Result]

At the beginning I was using method described here: [Joining two or more overlapping buffers using MMQgis plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268357/joining-two-or-more-overlapping-buffers-using-mmqgis-plugin), but it makes one point by dissolving all buffers  and then getting the centroid. In my example its possible to get more than 1 point without overlapping others so I'd like to ask if its possible to get the result which I described.

Comment: I'd like to solve: What are clusters?

Comment: related [Unions of SVG Point Markers In QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261121/unions-of-svg-point-markers-in-qgis/261123#261123)

Comment: Have you tried the `point cluster` style?

Comment: @JGH Point cluster would be nice if i had 1 type of symbols, but on 1 layer I have some points with different symbols. After using point cluser i would need to set style for each type pf symbol  separately, but in this tool is possible to set only one style (cluster symbol).

Comment: @Erik sorry, i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You basically want to create clusters, just as JGH pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `point cluster` style, it will aggregate multiple points together.

There is a hack to have multiple cluster symbols by creating one "super" style having **all** sub-styles, and to enable/disable each individual components.

To do so, create the `point cluster`, select the (unique) symbol and choose to `customize symbol`.

Add each desired components (in my example, a square, a star and the default circle). For each of them, click the data defined override symbol (the epsilon symbol) for the `size` and write a conditional statement: if the field value is what you want, set a size of 6, else, use a size of 0 to hide it.

```
if (my_field = 123, 6, 0)
```

For the default style, you can either remove it or exclude the already styled clusters

```
if (my_field not in (123,456), 6, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: To automatically adjust the colors, refer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362355/cluster-symbol-color-based-on-categorised-variables

Comment: Cool, thats what i wanted to get. But still i have some questions: 
1. Can i set distance of points clustering in the same layer depending on map scale? E.g. in 1:10000 scale, distance will be 16 map units, but in 1:25000 (when my symbols grows) distance will be 30 map units?
2. Can i set labels for each of cluster?

Comment: @DanielSobolewski for the variable distance I don't think so (not under 3.10 at least). For the labeling please ask a new question with enough detail (what should be displayed in the label etc) and see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282417/label-display-based-on-cluster-size)